# Delegate table cell to other tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, cell

I am working on project depends on `UITableView`. I have six main categories built in `UIStoryboard`. I want each cell to relate to another `UITableView`.

I do delegate using segue but it does not work. I need a method to delegate in the `UITableView` file:

```
class CategoriesView: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var OthersCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var StoreCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var ArtAndDesigneCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var StudentServicesCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var BeautyCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var CheefsCell: UITableViewCell!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if (segue.identifier=="CheefsCelll") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! CheefsView}
            else  if (segue.identifier=="BeautyCell") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! BeautyView}
            else if (segue.identifier=="StudentServicesCell") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! StudentServicesView}
            else  if (segue.identifier=="ArtAndDesigneCell") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! ArtAndDesigneView}
            else  if (segue.identifier=="StoreCell") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! StoreView}
            else  if (segue.identifier=="OthersCell") {let _=segue.destinationViewController as! OthersView}    
        }
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 6      
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `UITableViewDataSource` method `numberOfSectionsInTableView` must return a value different from 0. In your case it should be 1.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

If this does not work make sure you set the dataSource correctly in the IB or in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Ok. Did you check if the dataSource methods e.g. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are called and if the cell is dequeued correctly? What excatly does your table view display?

Comment: it does not display and refer to this line in AppDelegate file /                   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: Ok that error indicates that there might be a problem with the your outlets. It seems to me that there are some more problems in your code. 
Check out this tutorial about UITableView with custom cells. http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/